# Paypal IPN verification in Django

Tags: python, django, encoding

I am having unicode problems with verifying a IPN request.

I use the following function to verify the request.

```
def verify(self):
    parameters = self.params
    parameters['cmd'] = '_notify-validate'
    parameters = urllib.urlencode(dict([(k, v.encode(parameters['charset'])) for k, v in parameters.items()]) )
    return self.call_paypal(parameters) == 'VERIFIED'
```

The self.parmas is request.POST and this throws the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
```

A dump of the post can be found here: http://pastebin.com/sd2iwu41

I find it weird that there is an encoding error since I am using the same encoding paypal sends me.

Comment: Is `parameters` a Django `QueryDict`? If so you can simply do a `return self.call_paypal(parameters.urlencode())`.

Comment: I might be wrong but isn't a QueryDict readonly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `parameters` object is a Django `QueryDict`, it already has a very convenient [urlencode() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.urlencode) on it. Try something like this instead:

```
parameters = request.POST.copy()
parameters['cmd']='_notify-validate'
return self.call_paypal(parameters.urlencode()) == 'VERIFIED'
```

The [copy()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.copy) call is needed because the `QueryDict` from the `request` object is read-only. Calling `copy()` makes a mutable deep-copy that you are free to modify.

I do something like this in my Paypal IPN application and it has been working for some time.

Answer (score 0):

As your `self.params` contains some non ASCII characters so you have to encode this to `UTF-8` before passing to `urllib.urlencode`,  Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3997031/534790), it explains how to pass the parameters to `urlencode`.

Comment: Do you mean encode it to UTF-8 first and then encode it to whatever paypal is sending me? Cause if I send paypal the paramaters in a different encoding they will reject it.

Comment: `UnicodeEncodeError` is due to passing non ascii to `urllib.urlencode` so encode it first to `utf-8` as mentioned above.